# Why can't I load my local page using Webview

Tags: android, apache, .htaccess, webview, xampp

I came to seek help, I have search, read and tried several solutions I came across, but none seem to work for me,

I can't access my local website from the android emulator, using "http://10.0.2.2", but I tried it on other computer, and it works, I'm using Android Webview, does it have something to do with htaccess? How can I determine which htaccess is settings is in effect?

Is there anything I've missed to make it work, btw, when I try to access the local page using the builtin browser, I can access it without any troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the android.permission.INTERNET permission in your manifest? For more information see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: How did I know what? I guessed that your webview could not load the web page because your application did not have internet access.

Comment: +1, very nice guess... simple things are harder to spot against big things